# ¿Como puedo realizar esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito contar el numero de planillas que hay en un rango en la tabla `A`, y requiero que solo cuente el numero de planillas que sean de `TIPO` *`CORRECTIVO`*, el cual se encuentra en la tabla `B`, tengo la siguiente consulta pero me arroja un resultado o numero de planillas que no concuerda con el resultado correcto.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.PLANILLA) FROM acta_entrega A, control_planillas B
WHERE A.PLANILLA BETWEEN 002801 AND 002900
AND B.TIPO = 'CORRECTIVO'
```

Comment: pues claro, porque falta la condición del join entre tablas. Cómo se relacionan los datos entre ambas?

Comment: Tienes las tablas acta_entrega A, control_planillas B.  Cual seria la tabla C para poner la condicion C.Tipo?

Comment: Son tablas sin ninguna relación. se puede realizar así?

Comment: De alguna forma hay que relacionar los datos, alguna columna en común deben tener. Sino cómo pretendes que cuente el número de planilla de tipo correctivo, si el tipo está en la otra tabla y no tienen relación?

Comment: comprendo lo que me dicen, cambiare la estructura de la tabla, por que no tienen ninguna columna en común o existe alguna otra opción?.

Comment: lo que no entiendo es cómo quieres obtener el tipo de una planilla, si esa info no está en la otra tabla. Es como si te dijera que tengo una tabla con animales, una tabla con colores, y quiero obtener todos los gatos negros...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas relacionar las dos tablas mediante algún dato relacionado entre ellas

```
SELECT COUNT(A.PLANILLA) 
FROM acta_entrega A 
inner join control_planillas B ON A.CampoRelacionadoConPlantillas = B.CampoRelacionadoConEntrega
WHERE A.PLANILLA BETWEEN 002801 AND 002900
AND B.TIPO = 'CORRECTIVO'
```

En esta consulta deberías sustituir `CampoRelacionadoConPlantillas` y  `CampoRelacionadoConEntrega` con el nombre de los campos que relacionan tus tablas